# React Supabase Client Error with env url variable

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I'm trying to connect a react component to subabase.

[image]

The URL is correct. If I hardcoded it works.

But I am getting this Error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that you are console logging the `VITE_SUPABASE_URL`, but what value do you see? You need to include `https://` if that is missing.